# For MVN, zero covariance implies independence. How about other distributions?

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance, independence, nonparametric

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent) page on wikipedia, if $X\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$ with $\mu\in\mathbb R^2$ and $\Sigma\in\mathbb R^{2\times2}$ then we have $\textrm{Cov}(X_1,X_2)=0\implies X_1\perp\!\!\!\perp X_2$. Is this true for any other families of distribution besides the multivariate normal?

Comment: This is not true for all multivariate distributions.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll think about examples with some other exponential distributions...

Comment: Try it for the simplest possible case: Bernoulli random variables.